# add new element to NSManagedObject

Tags: cocoa, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject Class named "Person"

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Person)
public class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String
    @NSManaged public var secondName: String
}
```

in another view controller, i set the following variable:

```
var Persons = [Person]()
```

now i would like to add a new value to my variable Persons.
i tried something like this:

```
Persons.append(<newElement: Person>)
```

but which syntax i have to use for the placeholder `<newElement: Person>`
to add a new person with first and second name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the designated initializer

```
var people = [Person]() // variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

let newPerson = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Person", into:context) as! Person
newPerson.firstName = "John"
newPerson.lastName = "Doe"
people.append(newPerson)
```

`context` represents the managed object context of the Core Data stack.

To save the new object permanently to you have to save the context.

Comment: will this code save the values automatically into core data or only in the variable person? :)

Comment: You have to call `context.save` explicitly to save the data.